# remove() via lapply does not work

Tags: r, lapply

I want to remove some data.frames from the memory. This works well with

```
remove(ttest,inherits=T)
```

Now I don't want to write that for every data I used, so I thought about using lapply:

```
lapply(tablenames,remove)
```

where tablenames is just a list with the tablenames in it:

```
tablenames

[[1]]
[1] ttest
Levels: testsheet ttest ttest2

[[2]]
[1] testsheet
Levels: testsheet ttest ttest2

[[3]]
[1] ttest2
Levels: testsheet ttest ttest2
```

I always get back an error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : ... muss Namen oder Zeichenketten enthalten

which translates to "must contain name or string".

Next I tried to wrap the remove function into another function, also to give it the inherits=T parameter:

```
clean <- function(table) {rm(table, inherits=T)}
> lapply(tablenames,clean)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

The tables are still there. What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Unclear. What do you want? You want to remove some members of tablenamers?  Which?

Comment: No, I want to remove the whole tables from the memory, just like rm(table) or remove(table) does.

Comment: Why shouldn't you do rm(tablenames)?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know rm() accepts lists? Unfortunately this also doesn't work, it gives an Error  Error in rm(tablenames, inherits = T) : 
  cannot remove bindings from a locked environment . Can you explain that to me? tablenames is created right above and rm(ttest, inherits=T) works...

Comment: Sorry, if I run it outside the program it doesn't give an error, but still doesn't remove the tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything that complicated.  If `tablenames` is a character vector of the names of the objects to be removed then

```
rm(list = tablenames, inherits = TRUE)
```

will do what I think you want to do.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I just wasn't aware that a list is an allowed input for the function.

Comment: @mariego A list is not an allowed input, a character vector is an allowed input.

Comment: Ok, list=tablenames confused me. :)

Comment: Still I don't understand why lapply doesn't work when remove is just a function... :/

Comment: You could use lapply if you really want to, but you'd have to do this: `lapply(tablenames, function(a) rm(list = a, inherits = TRUE)`.  But be careful, because it looks as though your definition of `tablenames` includes the actual objects not just the names of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `lapply`, we should use `unlist`:

```
rm(list = unlist(tablenames))
```